# Creating a media player in only an android service

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to make a service that plays a single song in the background. The user enters the title of the song, it searches for it and plays it with no UI. I have the searching part down, but I have never used the android media player in a service and am getting a few errors.

Here is the sample code I have so far for searching:

```
ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
AudioManager mgr =(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
Intent sending = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
String command = intent.getStringExtra("command");
Log.v("MusicService",command);
sending.putExtra("command", command);
MusicService.this.sendBroadcast(sending);
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    null,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " LIKE ?",
    new String[]{"%"+command+"%"},
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC");
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
    matches.add(path);
    Log.v("MusicService",path);
```

And here is my code for running a media player:

```
MediaPlayer mplayer = new MediaPlayer();
mplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
String filePath = matches.get(0);
File file = new File(filePath);
try {
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    mplayer.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
    inputStream.close();
    mplayer.prepare();
    mplayer.start();
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error I'm currently getting is a handler on dead thread error but I'm not sure how to keep the thread alive until the media player is completed.

Comment: You should add some exception logging to your post. Also, if you are having threading issues then you need to tell us how you are managing the threads (ie: what thread is runing what code and when). Otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: I think I actually figured it out. What I didn't mention is that I was using an intentservice instead of a service so the thread was dying as soon as it completed all of its tasks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was coming from the fact that I used an intentservice instead of a service. I did not know that intentservice ended as soon as it processed all of its steps. I changed it over to a service and now it functions as expected.